# Minimal sets of foliations in the plane (generalisation of Poincaré-Bendixson)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Let $F$ be a $1$-dimensional foliation of an open subset of the plane defined by a
locally Lipschitz line field. Suppose $C$ is a compact minimal set of $F$ (i.e. $C$ is non-empty, compact, a union of leaves of $F$, and every leaf of $F$ contained in $C$ is dense in $C$).

Does this imply that $C$ is a compact leaf of $F$?

Remark: If $F$ is orientable then the (proof of the) Poincare-Bendixson
Theorem implies that this is so.